# Какова грамматическая основа этого предложения?

Tags: основа, предикатив

Но изначально он не одинок.

Грамматическая основа: "изначально не одинок" или "не одинок"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Грамматическая основа:***он не одинок.***